# Conditional evaluation of expression over columns in a pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, conditional-statements

I have following data frame:
[image]

I am trying to calculate sigma according to following rule based on CHART_TYPE column values according to following conditions:

```
If chart type is X-BAR -> SIGMA = (UPPER_CONTROL_LIMIT - LOW_CONTROL_LIMIT)/6
If chart type is MIN -> SIGMA = (TARGET - LOW_CONTROL_LIMIT)/3
If chart type is MAX -> SIGMA = (UPPER_CONTROL_LIMIT - TARGET)/3
```

Please advise

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be able to use `df.apply` here.

First, create a helper:

```
def func(row):
    if row['CHART_TYPE'] == 'X_BAR':
        return (row['UPPER_CONTROL_LIMIT'] - row['LOW_CONTROL_LIMIT']) / 6

    elif row['CHART_TYPE'] == 'MIN':
        return (row['TARGET'] - row['LOW_CONTROL_LIMIT']) / 3

    return (row['UPPER_CONTROL_LIMIT'] - row['TARGET']) / 3
```

Now, call `df.apply`:

```
df.SIGMA = df.apply(func, axis=1)
```